# Rails - Slug causing wrong id to be passed with edit controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a slug defined as following:

```
def slug
  name.downcase.gsub(" ", "-")
end
def to_param
    "#{id}-#{slug}"
end
```

My edit controller has the following:

```
@lightnovel = Lightnovel.find(params[:id])
```

In my edit view form:

```
<%= form_for(@lightnovel) do |f| %>
<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :name  %>
    <%= f.text_area :name %><br>
</div>
<div class = "field">
    <%= f.label :series  %>
    <%= f.text_area :series %><br>
</div>
<div class="actions"> 
  <%= f.submit %> 
</div> 
<% end %>
```

When i edit a record and submit it i am getting an error. The problem is the ID that it is using is from the modification from the slug instead of just the ID.(Attached below)

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"patch",
"authenticity_token"=>"8TGBnfKuhOBhd4YISAwtWMc0Lc4ZIkxOM3oeakgKkPvJKqyRo2jPWPHMwwXtVS5LfGCXviqVI4XhVPngfNWNHw==",
 "lightnovel"=>{"name"=>"CD",
 "series"=>"CD"},
 "commit"=>"Update Lightnovel",
 "id"=>"5-cd"}
```

The ID being used must be 5 instead of "5-cd". What should i do to change this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question:

It seems that the problem was not caused by the id rather it was due to the update action in my controller not being defined.

Once i defined it and added the @lightnovel var it worked.